# Can this Sample Entropy (SampEn) calculation be improved?

Tags: performance-tuning, time-series

I am interested in calculating various entropy measures of time series, and was surprised to find that none of them are included with Mathematica.  Sample Entropy (SampEn) is a fairly common technique for this purpose, so I've written a module to perform the calculation, but I'm surprised at how slow it is (especially compared to my Python implementation).

```
SampEn[TheData_,TheWindowSize_,TheThreshold_]:=
  Module[{Num=Length[TheData],NumWindows,TheValueArray1,TheValueArray2,TheDifferences1,,TheDifferences2},
  NumWindows=Num-TheWindowSize+1;
  TheValueArray1=Table[Table[TheData[[j]],{j,i,i+(TheWindowSize-1)}],{i,NumWindows}];
  TheValueArray2=Table[Table[TheData[[j]],{j,i,i+(TheWindowSize)}],{i,NumWindows-1}];
  TheDifferences1=Total[Table[Total[Table[If[ChessboardDistance[i,j]<TheThreshold,1,0],{j,TheValueArray1}]]-1,{i,TheValueArray1}]];
  TheDifferences2=Total[Table[Total[Table[If[ChessboardDistance[i,j]<TheThreshold,1,0],{j,TheValueArray2}]]-1,{i,TheValueArray2}]];
  -Log[N@(TheDifferences2/TheDifferences1)]];
RandomWalkingData=Accumulate[Table[1.0*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,.4]],{t,1,1000,1}]];
m=2;
r=0.2*StandardDeviation[RandomWalkingData];
Timing[SampEn[RandomWalkingData,m,r]]
```

This takes `40.04s` for 1000 datapoints, but with 5000 points it already takes `989.608s`. I also tried a variant that combined the `Table` and `Total` operations, but it wasn't any faster.

```
TheDifferences1=Total[Table[If[ChessboardDistance[i,j]<TheThreshold,1,0],{j,TheValueArray1},{i,TheValueArray1}],2]-Length[TheValueArray1];
```

Are there any shortcuts or built-in functions that can be used to speed up this calculation? How can this be made more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) did already the major part of the work by boiling down things to `Nearest`. I have only two further remarks:

1. `NearestFunctions` thread over lists, enabling parallelization.
2. The bandwidth limited (and thus expensive) list operations like `Rest` and `Flatten` can be avoided when it is just about counting the number of elements.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
ClearAll[sampleEnt2]
sampleEnt2[data_, ws_, t_] :=  Module[{nF1, nF2, diff1, diff2, va1, va2},
  va1 = Partition[data, ws, 1];
  va2 = Partition[data, 1 + ws, 1];
  nF1 = Nearest[va1 -> Automatic, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
  nF2 = Nearest[va2 -> Automatic, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
  diff1 = Total[(Length /@ nF1[va1, {All, t}])] - Length[va1];
  diff2 = Total[(Length /@ nF2[va2, {All, t}])] - Length[va2];
  -Log[N@(diff2/diff1)]
  ]
```

This is how it performs on my quad core machine:

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomWalkingData = 
  Accumulate[1.0 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .4], 1000]];
m = 2;
r = 0.2*StandardDeviation[RandomWalkingData];
SampEn[RandomWalkingData, m, r] // AbsoluteTiming
sampleEnt[RandomWalkingData, m, r] // AbsoluteTiming
sampleEnt2[RandomWalkingData, m, r] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {36.0335, 0.120787}
>
> {0.02856, 0.120787}
>
> {0.006953, 0.120787}

Comment: +1, great points.

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[sampleEnt]
sampleEnt[data_, ws_, t_] :=   Module[{nF1, nF2,  diff1,  diff2,
    va1 = Partition[data, ws, 1], va2 = Partition[data, 1 + ws, 1]},    
  nF1 = Nearest[va1 ->"Index", DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
  nF2 = Nearest[va2 -> "Index", DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
  diff1 = Length[Flatten[Rest[nF1[#, {All, t}]]& /@ va1]];
  diff2 = Length[Flatten[Rest[nF2[#, {All, t}]]& /@ va2]];
 -Log[N @ (diff2 / diff1)]]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
ss = 500;
RandomWalkingData = Accumulate[Table[1.0 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .4]],
 {t, 1, ss, 1}]];
m = 2;
r = 0.2*StandardDeviation[RandomWalkingData];
Timing[sampleEnt[RandomWalkingData, m, r]]
```

> {0.007999, 0.482223}

This is about  1500X speed-up versus OP's `SampEn` on the same input:

```
Timing[SampEn[RandomWalkingData,m,r]]
```

> {11.5612, 0.482223}

For a larger input size (`ss = 1000`) we get

```
Timing[sampleEnt[RandomWalkingData, m, r]]
```

> {0.029995, 0.26345439758666905}

```
Timing[SampEn[RandomWalkingData, m, r]]
```

> {46.099992, 0.26345439758666905}

Comment: Looks good, but I get an error `{.....{0.9616,0.9613,0.9716},{0.9613,0.9716,0.962},<<4299>>}->Index is neither a list of real points nor a valid list of rules.` using v10.4, and actually I don't understand what `->"Index"' means here.

Comment: Aaron, try `Nearest[va1 -> Automatic, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]`, instead. The syntax with `Index` was introduced around version 11.2. Both variants mean that only the positions should be looked up by `Nearest`, not the points themselves.